# dealing with the this keyword

Tags: javascript, this

Just now I started using the `this` keyword, and I have been wondering, why doesn't "this" work?

```
var obj = {
    thas: this,
    obj2: {
        obj3: {
            thos: this,
            lol: "lol",
            pap: function() {
                console.log(obj.obj2.obj3.lol);
                console.log(this.lol);
                console.log(thos.lol);
            }
        }
    }
};

obj.obj2.obj3.pap();
```

take a look at the third `console.log()`.

I am defining the variable so why am I this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: thos is not defined`

Comment: For what it's worth, `thas: this` and `thos: this` refer to the same object: the enclosing scope of wherever you're executing this code.

Comment: @MikeC but they are inside different objects

Comment: [But that's not how Javascript binding works](https://jsfiddle.net/18ua1cu8/). The value of `this` is defined based on the scope of the executing code, not on the resulting data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `thos` needs to referenced in the same way as `lol`. You used `this.lol` to access `lol`, so to access `thos` you have to access `this.thos`, which probably wouldn't work as `this.thos.lol`. OOP gets weird sometimes. If you want to use `thos` instead, define it outside of the object and give that a try...

EDIT: Here's the modified code:

```
// this is the new line:
var thos = this;

var obj = {
    thas: this,
    obj2: {
        obj3: {
            lol: "lol",
            pap: function() {
                console.log(obj.obj2.obj3.lol);
                console.log(this.lol);
                console.log(thos.lol);
            }
        }
    }
};

obj.obj2.obj3.pap();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Im not understanding what you are proposing would look like in code

Comment: I changed my answer with modified code. This will allow you to use `thos` instead of `this`, but not `thas`

Answer (score 3):

[As MDN tells us:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

> A function's `this` keyword behaves a little differently in JavaScript
>   compared to other languages. It also has some differences between
>   strict mode and non-strict mode.
>
> In most cases, the value of `this` is determined by how a function is
>   called. It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be
>   different each time the function is called. ES5 introduced the bind
>   method to set the value of a function's this regardless of how it's
>   called, and ECMAScript 2015 introduced arrow functions whose this is
>   lexically scoped (it is set to the this value of the enclosing
>   execution context).

When a function is called as a method of an object, its `this` is set to the object the method is called on. So, `this.lol` works fine and equals to just calling `lol`, since they're both in the scope.

But what happens when `thos.lol` is called? Since `this` is set an object property value, the virtual machine thinks `this` is in global scope:

> In the global execution context (outside of any function), this refers to the global object, whether in strict mode or not.

So, you call `thos.lol`, it sees the global object and gives you undefined error. Try to `obj.obj2.obj3.thos.lol;` in console and you'll see undefined. Try to `obj.obj2.obj3.thos;` in console and you'll see the global object.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to explain that, it is much clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to the parent object when referred to in an object's property. Inside of the `pap()` method you can declare:

`var thos = this;`

Then you can do:

`console.log(thos.lol);`

Comment: wait, in global scope?

Comment: In the method. Even inside the `pap` method, `this` refers to the parent object.

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to access `thos` when it's not in scope. `pap: function() { }` creates a new function scope that doesn't know anything about `thos`, so you need to either pass it in or do `console.log(obj.obj2.obj3.thos.lol);` instead of just `console.log(thos.lol);`